# React rest-hooks how to Authentication

Tags: reactjs, django, typescript, django-rest-framework, rest-hooks

I am trying to build the authentication part of my frontend project so it can communicate with the [DRF](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/) API. I decided also to use [rest-hooks](https://resthooks.io/) to fetch and send data from / to the API.

I am reading [rest-hooks auth documentation](https://resthooks.io/docs/guides/auth) as a guide but I can't find the "proper way" to implement it in my project. Everything I have read so far is using resources to fetch and send data to the API.

In the backend I have this `/api-auth` endpoint that after sending `username` & `password` parameters it returns a token to use as a header while fetching, I guess this is the "easy" part.

Despite I am trying to understand the rest-hooks documentation I can't figure out how to bring this together using DRF API + rest-hooks.

And plus, besides everything I have said above, I have tried this anyway, and is not working...

### Attempts

I created this `AuthResource` to attach to the login form.

#### With the `fetch` approach:

```js
import { Resource } from '@rest-hooks/rest';
import { API_URL } from '../utils/server';

export default class AuthResource extends Resource {
    static getFetchInit = (init: RequestInit) => ({
        ...init,
        credentials: 'same-origin'
    });
}
```

**Error:**

> Class static side 'typeof AuthResource' incorrectly extends base class static side 'typeof Resource'.
>
> The types of 'getFetchInit(...).credentials' are incompatible between these types.
>
> Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'RequestCredentials | undefined'.

- With the second approach

#### With the `superagent` approach:

```js
import { Request } from 'rest-hooks';

class AuthdResource extends Resource {
  static fetchPlugin = (request: Request) => request.withCredentials();
}
```

It cannot find `Request` inside module `rest-hooks`.

Comment: It's crazy that these codes are copied straight from the docs and they have errors!  But I am seeing the errors too.  I'm actually getting an additional error on both setups because the classes extend `Resource` which extends `SimpleResource` which extends `Entity` which has an `abstract` method `pk(parent?: any, key?: string): string | undefined;` which is not implemented anywhere.

Comment: it is not crazy, maybe if you read the question you would be able to read also that I am asking what is the proper method to do authentication. And I did not implemented `pk()` for the reason above.

Comment: It feels like you are attacking me which I don't get because I am not attacking you, I am attacking the authors of this package!  I can fix the `fetch` approach error.  I'll write you an answer.  I can't fix the `superagent` approach because there is no `Request` exported from `rest-hooks`.

Comment: meh, it felt like an attack saying that I copied the code and even with errors. But I did that,  just trying to "bring some light" (to myself).

Comment: I'm sorry if it came out wrong.  What I meant is that you have copied these straight from the docs so I know that you aren't doing anything wrong and haven't screwed anything up because this is exactly what the docs say to do (I'm honestly not familiar with this package).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'RequestCredentials | undefined'.

Typescript infers the return type of `getFetchInit` as having the property `{ credentials: string }` because it sees `'same-origin'` as just `string`.  The expected return type `RequestInit` only allows for specific literal strings in the union type `RequestCredentials`.  `'same-origin'` is one of those strings, so the value is fine.  We just need to get Typescript to interpret it more specifically than `string`.

One way to do this is by using an [`as const` assertion](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-4.html#const-assertions), which means that the return type includes the literal value of the string `{ credentials: 'same-origin' }`.

```
credentials: 'same-origin' as const
```

The other way (which I like better) is to annotate the return type for the `getFetchInit` method rather than letting it be inferred.  We want it to return a `RequestInit` object.

```
export class AuthResource extends Resource {
    static getFetchInit = (init: RequestInit): RequestInit => ({
        ...init,
        credentials: 'same-origin'
    });
    pk(parent?: any, key?: string | undefined): string | undefined {
        return;
    }
}
```

That fixes the `fetch` approach.  The `superagent` approach I cannot fix because I am getting the same error as you are that `Request` is not exported from `rest-hooks`.  I don't know where this import is supposed to come from because you are doing exactly what it says to do in the docs and it doesn't work.